# Can we exchange messages between background script and popup.js if the popup.js is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I setup a popup.js in which there is a button, when I click on the button, I can exchange messages with content-script or background.js, but when the page reloads, i.e. popup.js is closed, can I send a message from background.js to popup.js in order to get a value without opening the popup?

```js
background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
      
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ myname: "popup-message", data: "Hello from background.js" });
  }
  return true;
});
```

```js
popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.myname === "popup-message") {
    console.log("Received message from background.js:", message.data);
  }
});
```

When I run the above code, it console logs an error in the background.js :- `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`

Comment: Generally, no. Closing the popup is similar to closing a tab/page. Everything running in the popup's context is terminated. Because of this, the popup should really only contain enough to show a UI and communicate with background, where all the work is done.

Comment: I am not able to find a solution for this problem, I would really appreciate your help on this :-
So after the manifest version 3, tabCapture API does not work in content and background script, it can only work in popup.js, so once the user open a popup.js, but I have seen other screen recording extensions recording tabs without communicating with popup.js, they just inject code on content script and once the user clicks on the capture current tab button, it starts the recording

Comment: @Ouroborus, I am not really sure how is this happening, I guess they are using version 2 of manifest, but how can I do this with version 3 now?

Comment: Does your extension request the appropriate permissions? To use tabCapture, you'd need to request the tabCapture permission in the manifest (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabCapture/)).

Comment: Also, maybe [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/issues/627#issuecomment-1365477381) and [this](https://github.com/wireworks-app/chrome-screen-recording) might help

Comment: @Ouroborus, I had given the necessary permissions, but I think tabCapture don't work in background.js anymore:-  [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/commit/c4fbd65149e40c04d77daf85190d4ab7ef163b06#diff-17af00c96d2f067281772485570c05ead1720cb98d13fee26d5910c4b1b1a3fbL171]

Comment: @Ouroborus, Yes, I tried the above example, but as I said, after the page reloads, in order to make a recording continue, I needs to have a new streamId from popup.js, that's why I asked the question that can it send message from popupjs automatically without opening it

Comment: @Ouroborus, The problem with send example is that its using desktopCapture, which prompts the user to select which screen they want to share, I want to enable use to record the current tab without giving the prompt